# Multiple Resource Cell Selection in FullCalendar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/demos) and I want to drag and select cells of multiple resources at the same time to perform some action. I couldn't find any solution to this in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/demos) and right now I am able to drag and select only a single row/resource.
Looking forward for any help.

Thank You in advance :)

[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umX8d.png)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible through the UI at the moment. Perhaps you can make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to get it added

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.